# shortest uncommon subsequence

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given two strings s and t, determine length of shortest string z such that z is a subsequence of s and not a subsequence of t.

example :

s :babab, t :babba

sol : 3 (aab)

not looking for copy pastable code, please if anybody can help with intution for solving this.

thanks a lot !

Comment: @CarySwoveland, as far as I understand he means that he wants a subsequence of the first one that is not present in the second one at any place, or a subsequence from the second one that is not present in the first one at any place.

Comment: @subspring, that would make more sense, and is consistent with the statement of the problem. I've deleted my comment.

Comment: check this article https://tutorialspoint.dev/algorithm/dynamic-programming-algorithms/shortest-uncommon-subsequence, it contains exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @subspring this article is not opening

Comment: Check this one https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-uncommon-subsequence/.

Comment: Proposed algorithm: Step 1: Build a clever data structure that will allow to answer the question "Is this given string a subsequence of t?" efficiently. I suggest a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). Step 2: Use a "sliding window" algorithm to iterate on the shortest substrings of s.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic programming to solve this in quadratic time just like the longest common subsequence. I'll show the formula and how you would come up with it.

First, some definitions. Let `m` be the length of `S`, and let `n` be the length of `T`. Define `DP(i, j)` as the length of the shortest subsequence of `S[:i]` that is not a subsequence of `T[:j]`, or 'INF' if none exists. Here, the expression `S[:i]` is slice notation meaning 'the first `i` characters of `S`, so `S[:0]` is empty and `S[:m]` is all of `S`. We want `DP(m, n)`.

There's two easy base cases: Since `T[:0]` is empty, any character in `S` will work, so `DP(i, 0) = 1 if i > 0`. Similarly, `DP(0, j) = 'INF' for all j`.

Now, we just have to write a general formula for `DP(i, j)` which only depends on the value of `DP()` on indices smaller than `(i, j)`. The last character of `S[:i]` is just some character `S[i-1]`. Either our optimal subsequence for `S[:i], T[:j]` ends with `S[i-1]` or it doesn't.

- If our optimal subsequence doesn't end with `S[i-1]`, then we can delete `S[i-1]` from consideration, and our answer is `DP(i, j) = DP(i-1, j)`.

If our optimal subsequence does end with `S[i-1]`, then we need to know the rightmost occurrence of `S[i-1]` in `T[:j]`.

- If `S[i-1]` does not occur in `T[:j]` at all, then `S[i-1]` by itself is a shortest subsequence, so `DP(i, j) = 1`.
- Otherwise, let `Rightmost(c, j)` be the rightmost index of `T[:j]` equal to some character `c`. Since we are using `S[i-1]` to end our optimal subsequence, we can ignore all the characters in `T[:j]` after the rightmost occurrence of `S[i-1]`: they can no longer affect whether a string is a subsequence of `T[:j]`. So then `DP(i, j) = DP(i-1, Rightmost(S[i-1], j)) + 1`, where the `+1` comes from the fact that we did choose to use `S[i-1]`.

Putting those together, the general formula for `i, j > 0` becomes:

```
DP(i, j) = 1 if (S[i-1] not in T[:j]), or 

         = min(DP(i-1, j),
               DP(i-1, Rightmost(S[i-1], j)) + 1) otherwise.
```

Since `Rightmost(c, j)` is always less than `j` by definition, we've achieved a formula using only indices smaller (lexicographically) than `(i, j)`, and we can use that formula directly for a recursive algorithm.